# If I split my harddrive, will a system restore delete it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, restore, desktop-computer, system-restore

I split my 1TB HD from C drive and called it A. I put some files there to back up. I have now come to a point where I need to run a system restore with the discs that came with my computer. If I do a system restore and wipe C drive clean, will I lose the part of the hard drive that I split or will it remain intact and my files uncorrupted? This is a partition I created with windows myself, and dragged files over to it. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you means a system restore from a backup you made, or from some OEM build in restore partition. In the OEM case: make backups on another drive and disconnect it. In the windows case: See Jared's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System restore only affects Windows OS system files and settings, and should not affect custom data on the A: Drive.

However any programs installed on that drive will likely be affected.